# Vmware and cursor in each running OS machine

Tags: keyboard, vmware-workstation, cursor

does each instance of running OS in Vmware workstation have "its keyboard and mouse cursor"? Ie. can I virtualize 5 robots in each system to do tasks with keyboard and cursor separately?

Maybe this is obvious, but since I know many obvious things often don't work, i rather ask it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the keyboard and mouse are there, even while not used for input in the VM, e.g. when you switched back to the host system. It's not like switching VM focus pulls the "virtual USB cords" out of the VM.

Comment: imagine separate auto-script running in every of 5 instances of vmware machine, will it work? do they have separate simulated keyboard and mouse instances?

Comment: @František I don't see a reason why not. The systems still have a mouse and keyboard, even though at that moment there's no connection between them and the physical hardware. That connection is virtual anyway, the VMware application receives input and forwards it to the VMs.

Answer (score 0):

No they will not!! Maybe they will be able to make clicks and if that's enough for you it's ok.
But for me it is essential to have a visible cursor in each VM which does not happen.